# Is user listing on wordpress private?

Tags: user-access, private

I'm creating a website using Wordpress. Users are registering on it as "Subscribers". When you register, you have a small panel with some custom info on it (that I made, creating a custom template)

Each user shouldn't know other users exist.

I started developing this without knowing if when registered users are available "to the world" (google indexing them, for example).

Is user registration data is publicy available in a Wordpress installation, by some url, perhaps? Can Anonymous users see registered ones, or can Registered Ones see all others registered ones? Where I can get this information on wordpress docs? Are registered users on Wordpress supposed to be available to all?

I couldn't get any information about this. Can someone help?

Comment: i take it by your reference to "google" that this "small panel" of user info is visible on the front end, have you looked at your source code to pinpoint something like a div css selector name and ran a search through your files to locate where this panel is and then zap the whole div?

Comment: @Martin: I think my question wasn't clear... I'm asking if all user registration data is publicy available in a Wordpress installation, by some url: can Anonymous users see registered ones, or can Registered Ones see all others registered ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, user data is not visible to the outside world, or to google, unless you specifically make it visible in the theme somehow.

One piece of user data is exposed for authors of posts though. Specifically, their login names are visible in many places.